# Move up Flutter AlertDialog

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to do something with Flutter.io
But i have some problems. Its not well documented for my Action.

I want to get an Android Application with an AlertDialog. But my keyboard are over the Alertdialog. So i found a workaround to push the Dialog up when the keyboard opens, but i dont really understand it.

So my plan is to move up the AlertDialog. Its centered at the moment. I want to add an Margin bottom to the "AlertDialog".

Here is my function which will opens the Dialog if i click the Fabbutton.

```
void _openNewInputPopup() {
    print("popup will open");

    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(
      content: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('Wie lautet das Versteck?',
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
            new TextField(onChanged: (String value) {
              {
                print("changed $value");
              }
            },),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      actions: <Widget> [
        new FlatButton(onPressed: () {
          _dialogResult(MyDialogAction.Abbrechen);
        }, child: new Text('Abbrechen')),

        new FlatButton(onPressed: () {
          _dialogResult(MyDialogAction.Anlegen);
          }, child: new Text('Anlegen')),
      ]
    );


    showDialog(context: context, child: dialog);
  }
```

It would be very nice if someone of you has a little bit more experience with flutter and could help me :) Thanks

Comment: There is a fix work-in-progress to move dialogs up when the keyboard appears https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/15426

Comment: thanks, but i am to stupid to understand how this really works..

Comment: I didn't have a closer look at this myself. I guess you'd need to use MediaQuery to get the current size and adjust the layout accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I adjust padding according to textfield has focus or not. I hope it will help..

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: yourFocus.hasFocus ? 
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 250 // adjust values according to your need
                        : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 130),// adjust values according to your need
                child: AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("your Alert header text"),
                    content: TextField(
                             focusNode: yourFocus,
                             controller: yourTextController,
                             decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                                        hintText: "your hint text."),
                             ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                          child: Text("Your button Title"),
                          onPressed: () {
                           yourFunction();
                          })
                    ]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Add padding or margin to the bottom of parent Widget:

```
margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
```

OR

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
```

and add   `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` this to your Scaffold Widget